# Playing music even after the UI has been closed

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-pendingintent

Well I am a bit confused with the following.
I have a class (Main Player UI) that has the mediaplayer object.
Now the problem is that I want the music to played even after the UI has been disposed, hence I have to depend on the service.
But then if I move the MediaPlayer to the Service class

1. How am I going to control the onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) when the player UI is shown up, which also needs to show the change in the song? But then the  method has to be included in the Service method.
2. How do I make the Play buttons on the UI to start the song that is available in the Service method?

Please guide me. The current player class that holds the UI as well as the mediaplayer is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boombastic_player);


    //INITIALIZATIONS
    mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    utils = new Utilities();
    songProgressBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.string.seeker);
    play=(Button)findViewById(R.string.play);
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.string.next);
    previous=(Button)findViewById(R.string.previous);
    playlist=(Button)findViewById(R.string.Playlist);
    search=(Button)findViewById(R.string.search);
    repeat=(Button)findViewById(R.string.repeat);
    shuffle=(Button)findViewById(R.string.shuffle);
    starttime=(TextView)findViewById(R.string.startTime);
    endtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.string.endTime);
    ObjectIntermediate=new Intermediate();
    srvMplayer=new ServiceMan();


    //Preparation
    if(!Searched)
    {
        GetAllSongs();
        Searched=true;
        ShowToast("Finished Search");
    }

    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); 

    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // check for already playing
            if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                if(mMediaPlayer!=null)
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();

                    /* Release Service*/

                    // Changing button image to play button
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playback_play);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Resume song
                if(mMediaPlayer!=null)
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                    /* Starting Service*/

                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // check if next song is there or not
            if(isRepeat)
            {
                playSong(currentSongIndex);
            }
            else if(isShuffle)
            {
                ShuffleSong();
                playSong(currentSongIndex);
            }
            else if(currentSongIndex < (BoombasticPlayer.Songslist.size() - 1))
            {
                try 
                {
                    ShowToast(Integer.toString(currentSongIndex));
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("~~IllegalArgumentException~~",e.toString());
                    android.util.Log.e("->>" , "~~stacktrace~~", e);    
                } 
                catch (IllegalStateException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("~~IllegalStateException~~",e.toString());
                    android.util.Log.e("->>" , "~~stacktrace~~", e);
                }
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // play first song
                try 
                {
                    playSong(0);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("~~IllegalArgumentException~~",e.toString());
                    android.util.Log.e("->>" , "~~stacktrace~~", e);    
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("~~IllegalStateException~~",e.toString());
                    android.util.Log.e("->>" , "~~stacktrace~~", e);    
                }
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isRepeat)
            {
                playSong(currentSongIndex);
            }
            else if(currentSongIndex > 0)
            {
                try {
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // play last song
                try {
                    playSong(BoombasticPlayer.Songslist.size() - 1);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                currentSongIndex = BoombasticPlayer.Songslist.size() - 1;
            }
        }
    });

    playlist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent playlistIntent= new Intent(arg0.getContext(), Playlist.class);
            startActivityForResult(playlistIntent, MODE_APPEND);
        }
    });

    repeat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isRepeat==true)
            {
                isRepeat=false;
                ShowToast("Repeat OFF");
            }
            else
            {
                isRepeat=true;
                ShowToast("Repeat ON");
            }
        }
    });

    shuffle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isShuffle==true)
            {
                isShuffle=false;
                ShowToast("Shuffle OFF");
            }
            else
            {
                isShuffle=true;
                ShowToast("Shuffle ON");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You activity will need to communicate with the `Service` and vice versa. For example when the `Play` button is touched, you'll need to forward this action to the `Service`, and the `Service` will start the `MediaPlayer`. And the completion of the song will be intercepted in the `Service`, but forward to activity to update the ui.

Comment: @AndyRes thats what am not understanding, How do I achieve this? I have to have the onCompletion method and the mediaplayer in the service if I intend to play the song even after the UI has been destroyed. But then how do I synch this behaviour of the activity class,i.r UI n service class? :(